# Can WCF uses SOAP over TCP and get consumed by java client

Tags: java, wcf, soap, tcp

WCF used NetTCP Binding to exchange information by using TCP Protocol. Also SOAP is a Message formatting or protocol which is universally acceptable for interopertability between different technologies. So it is possible that when I developed any WCF service which uses TCP and SOAP Formatting it get consumed by java client or it will work only with Dot Net client as it used NetTCPBinding which may be Microsofts propritory binding for TCP based communication.

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes. The `NetTcpBinding` uses a custom [framing protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219293.aspx) created by Microsoft to be able to split the messages from the TCP stream. That binding also uses a [binary representation of XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219210.aspx) and the [SOAP structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219175.aspx), in addition to a [SOAP Extension which allows for reuse of commonly-used strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219190.aspx). As you can see from the links, all this information is public, and the documentation is quite comprehensive, so one could create a client on any platform to talk to a NetTcpBinding-based WCF endpoint.

In practice, I don't think anyone has done that, so such work wouldn't be something to be taken lightly (at that layer you'll be talking about dealing with socket communication anyway).

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "at that layer you'll be talking about dealing with socket communication anyway". What does it mean

Comment: Unless you have a framework which knows how to "talk" the framing and the binary representation of XML (which AFAIK there's none for Java), if you want to do that you'll need to write that framework yourself. And that means stiching bytes together and sending them over a TCP socket.